# Using VBA to click a javascript link, get "object required" error

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, ie-automation

I am attempting to access a website on IE using VBA to pull a report of the previous weeks transactions.  I was able to login and navigate to the report page.  However, when I try to click a link for an advanced search I get the error "Object Required"

Below is the HTML I have isolated as belonging to the link:

```
<!-- Form Actions -->


<input type="button" id="searchtTxn" value="Search"
    class="align-right margin-top"
    style="float: right; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 5px;">
**<div id="secondary-button"
    style="border: none; background: none; height: 26px; font-size: 11px; float: right;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="moreOptions" class="mouseover"><strong>More
            Options</strong>**
    </a>
</div>
```

Specifically, I am trying to select the "moreOptions" item.  I have also tried selecting based on the "mouseover" class with no luck.  I also tried to create a saved report that I could just click based on the class and ID, the HTML for this search is below:

```
<div class="div-scroll portletContentJS" 
 style="height:145px !important;" id="savedSearchPortlet" 
  style="overflow-y: auto;">


     <div class="savedsearch-record"> 
     <table style="width:100%;" class='draggable' >

     <tr>
         <td class="wrap-savedsearch-report">
         <div class="constrained"> 
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="searchtResultTxn hasTooltip"
          id="164035" style="text-decoration: underline;font-size:11px; padding-left: 2px;">Prev Week ACH </a>
           <div class="hidden"> 
            <!-- This class should hide the element, change it if needed -->
            <table>
               <tr> 
                    <td style='word-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-all;max-width:150px;min-width:50px;'>Prev Week ACH</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I am using the below VBA to access the website and navigate to the page I need.  The code errors out when I try to pull the Element "moreOptions".  I built in a 20 second wait time on the page that doesn't work in case the link wasn't available yet to no avail.  I have gone as high as 1 minute with no results.

```
Sub login1()
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim HTMLDoc As Object
  Dim objCollection As Object
  Dim allHREFs As New Collection


  Const navOpenInNewTab = &H800
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "https://www.treasury.pncbank.com/idp/esec/login.ht"

  Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: Loop

  Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

  With HTMLDoc
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("txtUserID").value = "XXXX"
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("txtOperID").value = "XXXXXX"
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("txtPwd").value = "XXXXXX"
  End With


  Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementById("loginFormButton")
  objCollection.Click

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
   Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementById("IR")
  objCollection.Click
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))
   Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementById("moreOptions")
  objCollection.Click
  Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: Loop
End Sub
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if you need additional details.  As it is a banking website I will not be able to provide login credentials but let me know if you need more of the HTML code.

**EDIT to Add Full Page HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">














<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>PINACLE - PNC</title>

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE;"/>

        <style>
            @import "/portal/shared/style/new-navigation/stylesheet.css";
            @import "/portal/shared/style/new-navigation/navbar.css";
        </style>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/shared/js/jQuery/jQuery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/shared/js/jQuery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>

        <!-- TeaLeaf config file needs to come before SDK -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/service/js/TealeafSDKConfig.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/service/js/TealeafSDK.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/shared/js/dojotoolkit/dojo/dojo.js"
            djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/shared/js/dojotoolkit/dojo/portal.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/shared/js/common/navigation.js"></script>

        <!-- Carousel - Navigation -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/shared/js/newPrimaryNav/navbar.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/shared/js/newPrimaryNav/jquery.tinycarousel2.js"></script>
        <!-- End Carousel - Navigation -->

        <!-- Draggable -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/shared/js/newPrimaryNav/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/shared/js/newPrimaryNav/draggable.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/portal/shared/style/jquery-ui.css">
        <!-- End Draggable -->

        <script type='text/javascript' src='/portal/shared/js/engine.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/portal/shared/js/util.js'></script>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='/portal/dwr/interface/PortletDisplayHelper.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/portal/dwr/interface/AjaxSessionManager.js'></script>

        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JScript" TYPE="text/javascript">

        </SCRIPT>












        <script type="text/javascript">
                (function() {
                    var host = '/tmmps/payee.js';
                    var sn = document.createElement('script');
                    sn.setAttribute('async', true);
                    sn.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
                    sn.setAttribute('src',  host);
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                    s.appendChild(sn);
                })();
        </script> 


    <!-- Add meta tag to enable PINACLE Smart App Banner on mobile devices -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ( /(iPad).*AppleWebKit.*Mobile.*Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
          var headNode = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
          var sbNode = document.createElement('meta');
          sbNode.name = 'apple-itunes-app';
          sbNode.content = 'app-id=804888748';
          headNode.appendChild(sbNode);
        } else if ( /(iPhone|iPod).*AppleWebKit.*Mobile.*Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
            var headNode = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            var sbNode = document.createElement('meta');                    
            sbNode.name = 'apple-itunes-app';                
            sbNode.content = 'app-id=874929964';
            headNode.appendChild(sbNode);
       }
    </script>

    <!-- Set the required variables for Web Analytics -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var page_data = {
            "site_name" : "pin",
            "language"  : "en",
            "brandname" : "PINACLE",
            "page_name" : "dashboard",
            "page_type" : "",
            "user_type" : "",
            "page_error" : [],
            "events" : []
        };
    <!-- Set the required theme values for EN Alerts -->
        var delay = setSecond(5);
        var mcSrc = '/portal/isc/ITS?svcnum=410&lte=999&relayState=newMessage&sky=xGTwyoiPngrh1eNFu3twqg%3d%3d';
    </script>

    <script id="pendo-snippet">
        var pendoFlag = 'Y';
        var pendoKey = '67a13df9-2e80-4942-4c32-6c799c2b8a67';
        var pendoUrl = 'https://cdn.pendo.io/agent/static/';
        var account = '10bf187d:013aea5bee72:50e1:01161136';
        var visitor = '08757603:016a2273446c:442c:7922f8fb';
        if(pendoFlag != null && pendoFlag == 'Y' ){ 
            (function(apiKey){
                (function(p,e,n,d,o){var v,w,x,y,z;o=p[d]=p[d]||{};o._q=[];
                v=['initialize','identify','updateOptions','pageLoad'];for(w=0,x=v.length;w<x;++w)(function(m){
                    o[m]=o[m]||function(){o._q[m===v[0]?'unshift':'push']([m].concat([].slice.call(arguments,0)));};})(v[w]);
                    y=e.createElement(n);y.async=!0;y.src=pendoUrl+apiKey+'/pendo.js';
                    z=e.getElementsByTagName(n)[0];z.parentNode.insertBefore(y,z);})(window,document,'script','pendo');

                    // Call this whenever information about your visitors becomes available
                    // Please use Strings, Numbers, or Bools for value types.
                    pendo.initialize({
                        visitor: {
                            id:  visitor
                        },          
                        account: {
                            id:  account 
                        }
                    });
            })(pendoKey);
        }
    </script>

    <!-- DTM tag for Web Analytics -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.adobedtm.com/1d90950c926aacaf003e1e8e48aeb1189d4d7901/satelliteLib-da0748631f5bf7f81de415cc298c402328aca822.js"></script>


    </head>


<body class="tundra" style="margin: 0px; overflow:hidden;">

<form name="frmLogOut" id="frmLogOut" method="post" action="/idp/esec/logout.ht">       
<input type="hidden" name="CST" id="CST" value="yQiJd0LUsfLawQPn9hibYKYebvjqQN2ek5F3WIO-Q6s"/>
</form>
<form name="pinacleMenuForm" method="post" action="/portal/isc/ITS" target="contentIframe">
    <input type="hidden" name="svcnum" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lte" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="relayState" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="sky" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" id="isLogoutProcessStart" name="isLogoutProcessStart" value="false"/>
</form>

<div id="portal-area">
        <div id="newNavContainer">





                        <a id="logo" class="logostyle" target="_top">
                            <img src='/portal/shared/images/logo_PINACLE.png?05222010' title='PINACLE Home' />
                        </a>


            <div class="utilitybar">
                <input type="hidden" id="isLogoutProcessStart" value="false"/>


                <!--  Start of Utility bar -->



                               <div id="utilityMenu" class="noarrow"><a id='LOUT' 
                                    href='/portal/esec/logout.ht~popup=N'">
                                    Log Out</a>
                                </div>      


                        <!-- Quick Links menu -->

                        <!-- End of Quick Links menu -->

                        <!--  Begin MessageCenter menu -->


                        <!-- End of MessageCenter menu -->

                        <!--  Begin Contact Us menu -->


                        <!-- End of Contact Us menu -->







                               <div id="utilityMenu" class="noarrow"><a id='HELP' 
                                    href='/portal/isc/ITS?svcnum=615&amp;lte=999&amp;relayState=Admin&amp;sky=n9wMfSLEaF8Tq%2Bq7BKeC%2BKOSkpw%3D~popup=N'">
                                    Help & Training</a>
                                </div>      


                        <!-- Quick Links menu -->

                        <!-- End of Quick Links menu -->

                        <!--  Begin MessageCenter menu -->


                        <!-- End of MessageCenter menu -->

                        <!--  Begin Contact Us menu -->


                        <!-- End of Contact Us menu -->








                        <!-- Quick Links menu -->





                                        <div class="arrow"><span class="top-levelQL">Quick Links</span>
                                            <div class="dropdown">

                                                <div id="utilityMenuQL"> 

                                                        <a id="HOME" href="https://www6.rbc.com/nj00-wcm/~popup=Y" target="_top">




                                                        Canada Express</a>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>



                        <!-- End of Quick Links menu -->

                        <!--  Begin MessageCenter menu -->


                        <!-- End of MessageCenter menu -->

                        <!--  Begin Contact Us menu -->


                        <!-- End of Contact Us menu -->








                        <!-- Quick Links menu -->

                        <!-- End of Quick Links menu -->

                        <!--  Begin MessageCenter menu -->


                        <!-- End of MessageCenter menu -->

                        <!--  Begin Contact Us menu -->

                                <div id="cntsMenu" class="arrow" >
                                    <span class="top-levelCNTS">Contact Us</span>

                                 <div class="dropdown">     



                                            <div class="contact-separator" id="utilityMenuCNTS"><a id='PNE' href='/portal/isc/ITS?svcnum=110&amp;lte=32&amp;relayState=Normal Login&amp;sky=hFBb%2BFaxIE2mbqyXUPb4QI8ujhw%3D~popup=N' 
                                                 target="_top">Phone & Email</a>
                                            </div>








                                </div>


                              </div>


                        <!-- End of Contact Us menu -->








                        <!-- Quick Links menu -->

                        <!-- End of Quick Links menu -->

                        <!--  Begin MessageCenter menu -->

                        <div id="mcMenu" class="arrow">
                            <span class="top-levelMC">Message Center</span>

                             <div class="dropdown">



                                        <div id="utilityMenuMC"><a id='MC' href='/portal/isc/ITS?svcnum=410&amp;lte=999&amp;relayState=managerUser&amp;sky=zUUFoarcvOhT%2BHZsvYhGUxdTrMY%3D~popup=N'
                                             target="_top">View Messages</a>
                                        </div>






                                        <div id="utilityMenuMC"><a id='EVXCN' href='/portal/isc/ITS?svcnum=411&amp;lte=999&amp;relayState=normalLogin&amp;sky=WYvYvPEHQiONA%2FJVJ6Nv2ixnfgc%3D~popup=N'
                                             target="_top">Create Notifications</a>
                                        </div>






                                        <div id="utilityMenuMC"><a id='EVXMN' href='/portal/isc/ITS?svcnum=411&amp;lte=999&amp;relayState=evxMngNotifications&amp;sky=14NR7J0sK%2F%2BOBBwvjZ2KL4sccxE%3D~popup=N'
                                             target="_top">Manage Notifications</a>
                                        </div>




                            </div>

                            </div>


                        <!-- End of MessageCenter menu -->

                        <!--  Begin Contact Us menu -->


                        <!-- End of Contact Us menu -->







                               <div id="utilityMenu" class="noarrow"><a id='PROF' 
                                    href='/portal/isc/ITS?svcnum=120&amp;lte=779&amp;relayState=Admin&amp;sky=XLwwWwsdoebibPHq17ltTwMaQRY%3D~popup=N'">
                                    My Profile</a>
                                </div>      


                        <!-- Quick Links menu -->

                        <!-- End of Quick Links menu -->

                        <!--  Begin MessageCenter menu -->


                        <!-- End of MessageCenter menu -->

                        <!--  Begin Contact Us menu -->


                        <!-- End of Contact Us menu -->






                            <input type="hidden" id="homemenuurl" value="/portal/shared/js/dashboard/dashboard.html" />


                               <div id="utilityMenu" class="noarrow"><a id='HOME' 
                                    href='/portal/shared/js/dashboard/dashboard.html~popup=N'">
                                    Home</a>
                                </div>      


                        <!-- Quick Links menu -->

                        <!-- End of Quick Links menu -->

                        <!--  Begin MessageCenter menu -->


                        <!-- End of MessageCenter menu -->

                        <!--  Begin Contact Us menu -->


                        <!-- End of Contact Us menu -->





                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

                        <div id="mcSecurityCenter" class="securitycenter">
                            <a href='/portal/isc/ITS?svcnum=-201&amp;tgt=L1BOU1dlYi9zaG93L2NvbnRlbnQvdHlwZS9TZWN1cml0eQ==~popup=N'
                            target="_top">
                            <img src='/portal/shared/images/shield.gif' 
                                alt="Security Center" title="Security Center"/></a>
                         </div>

            </div>          

        <div id="navbar">
        <input type="hidden" id="keepaliveuri" value='/portal/modulecontainer/keepmealive.ht'/>
            <a class="buttons prev" href="#"></a>
            <div id="tabs" class="viewport">
                <ul class="overview ui-sortable" id="sortable">

                    <li class="border-right"><a class="cursor" id='IR' menuId = '11084' 
                        href="/portal/isc/ITS?svcnum=277&amp;lte=999&amp;relayState=normalLogin&amp;sky=M2ePfNeGG85McrNpd8XuyGxkYTg%3D~popup=N" text="Information Repting" onClick="pendoFunction('')" >                    
                            <span class="center-align">
                                Information <br> Reporting
                            </span>
                        </a>
                         <div id="keepaliveind" data="N"></div>         
                    </li>

                    <li class="border-right"><a class="cursor" id='SRS' menuId = '35' 
                        href="/portal/isc/ITS?svcnum=966&amp;lte=999&amp;relayState=normalLogin&amp;sky=U9HtsOKdAoQPfjSFA2vaeecoieQ%3D~popup=N" text="Spl Rpts Svc" onClick="pendoFunction('')" >                   
                            <span class="center-align">
                                Special <br> Reports
                            </span>
                        </a>
                         <div id="keepaliveind" data="N"></div>         
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <a class="buttons next" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-divider"></div>


        <div id="blankDivIR" style="height:0px;width:100%">
            <iframe id='blankiframeIR' style='width:100%;height:0px'
                scrolling="NO" noresize marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"
                src='/ir/irOpeningPage/initialize.htm'>
            </iframe>
        </div>


        <div id="blankDiv" style="height:0px;width:100%">
        <iframe id='blankiframe' style='width:100%;height:0px'
            scrolling="NO" noresize marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"
            src='/portal/isc/blank.jsp'>
        </iframe>
        </div>  

        <div id="pingRequestsDiv" style="height:0px;width:100%">
            <iframe id='pingRequestsiframe' style='width:100%;height:0px'
                scrolling="NO" noresize marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"
                src='/idp/pingRequests.ht'>
            </iframe>
        </div>

        <div id="alertDiv" style="height:0px;width:100%">
            <iframe id='alertiframe' style='width:100%;height:0px' 
                scrolling="NO" noresize marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"
                src='/portal/isc/blank.jsp'>
            </iframe>
        </div>

        <div id="contentDiv" style="height:87%;width:100%"> 
        <iframe id='contentIframe' name='contentIframe' style='height:100%;width:100%' 
                marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" 
                src='/portal/shared/js/dashboard/dashboard.html'>
        </iframe>
        </div>

        <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Session About To Expire" style="display: none;">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;border-color: #334455"></span>Your PINACLE session is going to expire. Do you want to extend it ?</p>
        </div>

        <div id="dialog-confirm-non-pnc" title="Session About To Expire" style="display: none;">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;border-color: #334455"></span>Your session is going to expire. Do you want to extend it ?</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>  
<!-- Footer tag for Web Analytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">_satellite.pageBottom();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >var _cf = _cf || []; _cf.push(['_setFsp', true]);  _cf.push(['_setBm', true]); _cf.push(['_setAu', '/resources/54334735b2196aff2ba74ad5d5844c']); </script><script type="text/javascript"  src="/resources/54334735b2196aff2ba74ad5d5844c"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: After clicking the login button, whether it will open a new window or tab? I have tested your code on my side, after login success, it will stay on the same tab, your VBA script works well on my side. From your login page, I notice that you are using an Iframe tag, please check whether there have an Iframe tag outside the "More option" button. As we all known, if we want to find element inside the iframe tag, first, we need to find the Iframe tag first, then access the element.

Comment: Besides, please check the Html code, from the existing code, it seems that there doesn't contain one html element which id property is "IR".

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT When the login button is clicked it redirects to a new page, there are no new tabs or windows opened. There is an iFrame tag: `<iframe name="contentIframe" id="contentIframe" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; visibility: visible;">
  </iframe>`  Do I access this in the same way I have accessed other elements and then access the "More Options" element? For your second comment regarding the "IR" id. This is on the initial page once login is completed and gets me to the page where I want to click the "More Option" link.

Comment: Please check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C3g3.png), if the elements located inside the <iframe> tag, we have to find the iframe tag first, then access the elements. If the elements located outside the <iframe> tag, generally, we could access the element via the IE.Document.getElementById method. After login success, try to use F12 developer tools to find the "More Options" element, and check whether it is exist and check whether its parent element contains an iframe tag.

Comment: Besides, according to your code and description, the elements (ID property is "IR" and "moreOptions") are located in the same page, it seems that you could find the "IR" element (which ID property is "IR"), but can't find the "moreOptions" elements, please try to use F12 developer tools to check if there have any difference? Can you post the whole page source which contains the "IR" and "moreOptions" elements or capture a screenshot about it, it might be easier for us to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I was able to determine that the "moreOptions" element is inside of the iFrame, I edited my original message to pull in the full HTML for the page.  I see that the "IR" element is outside of the iFrame.  Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was able to determine that the "moreOptions" element is inside of
>   the iFrame, I edited my original message to pull in the full HTML for
>   the page. I see that the "IR" element is outside of the iFrame.

To access the elements located inside the  tag, we have to find the iframe tag first, then access the elements. You try to use the following code to get elements from the Iframe:

```
IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementbyId("txtcontentinput").Value = "BBB"
IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementbyId("btncontentSayHello").Click
```

[Note] The array index starts from 0. If the website contains multiple iframe tag, make sure using the right array index. Also, you could use the getElementbyId() method to find the iframe tag.

Detail sample code as below:

index page:

```
<input id="txtinput" type="text" /><br />
<input id="btnSayHello" type="button" value="Say Hello" onclick="document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Hello ' + document.getElementById('txtinput').value" /><br />
<div id="result"></div><br />
<iframe width="500px" height="300px" src="vbaiframecontent.html">

</iframe>
```

vbaframeContent.html

```
<input id="txtcontentinput" type="text" /><br />
<input id="btncontentSayHello" type="button" value="Say Hello" onclick="document.getElementById('content_result').innerText = 'Hello ' + document.getElementById('txtcontentinput').value" /><br />
<div id="content_result"></div>
```

The VBA script as below:

```
Sub extractTablesData1()    
    Dim IE As Object   

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate ("<your website url>")

        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        'access elements outside the iframe tag and set value.
        IE.Document.getElementbyId("txtinput").Value = "AAA"
        IE.Document.getElementbyId("btnSayHello").Click

        'access elements inside the iframe tag.

    IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementbyId("txtcontentinput").Value = "BBB"
    IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementbyId("btncontentSayHello").Click



    End With
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

After running the script, the result as below:

[image]